# Close container with pure css using :target selector

Tags: html, css, hover, target

I have the following html:

I want to apply that `display: none;` when the `:target` is encountered.

If I don't use `:hover` that works just fine how you can check in the second example of the added fiddle, but if I add hover that is not working and I don't understand why :|

```css
#test1:target {
  display: none;
}
#container:hover #test1 {
  display: block
}
#test1 {
  display: none;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px dashed orange;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  HOVER ME
  <div id="test1">
    <a href="#test1">CLOSE ME</a>
    <p>
      CLOSE THIS CONTENT
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Here is the fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/adzFe/2838/)**

Answer (score 2):

You need to increase the specificity of the selector by adding `#container` to hide it -

```
#container:hover #test1:target {
    display: none;
}
```

```css
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border: 1px solid lime;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}
#container:hover #test1:target {
display: none;
}
#container:hover #test1, #container:hover #test2{display: block}
#test1{
  display: none;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px dashed orange;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}


#container:hover #test2:target {
display: none;
}
#test2{
  display: none;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px dashed orange;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!--example one with hover not working-->
<div id="container"> HOVER ME
<div id="test1">
<a href="#test1">CLOSE ME</a> 
<p>CLOSE THIS CONTENT</p>
</div>
</div>
<hr>

<!--example two without hover it's working-->
<div id="container"> DISPLAYED 
<div id="test2">
<a href="#test2">CLOSE ME 2</a> 
<p>CLOSE THIS CONTENT 2</p>
</div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle updated - http://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/adzFe/2839/](http://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/adzFe/2839/)

Comment: Brilliant !!!  only one thing, why the hover is not working after close the container ? :|  I mean the second time when you try to open the container by hovering over it is not displayed :|  http://jsfiddle.net/adzFe/2840/

Answer (score 1):

Actually not really possible to have that container prompt again on hover using :target selector. I suggest you to use :active instead. Works like charm.

```css
body {
    padding: 20px;
}
.container {
    border: 1px solid lime;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}
.container:hover .test1:active {
    display: none;
}
.container:hover .test1 {
    display: block
}
.test1 {
    display: none;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px dashed orange;
    background: green;
    padding: 10px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.bubu {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 Drop down menu
 <div class="test1">
  <a class="bubu" href="#">CLOSE ME</a>
  <p class="content">
   CLOSE THIS CONTENT
  </p>
 </div>
</div>
```